# Join two arrays and create only one element in the array

Tags: php

I want to join two arrays to send via json_encode. I'll show you my php:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT AQuenteSan, AFriaSan, dioxcloro, TemCaldeira, TemAQuente, TemAFria, TemBQuente, TemBFria, PH, Realizacao 

FROM raddb.Reg_legInt WHERE Realizacao BETWEEN ? AND ?");

$query->execute([$inicio, $fim]);

$json = array();
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);

    $json[]= [(string)$AQuenteSan, (string)$AFriaSan, (string)$dioxcloro, (string)$TemCaldeira, (string)$TemAQuente, (string)$TemAFria, 
    (string)$TemBQuente, (string)$TemBFria, (string)$PH, (string)$Realizacao];
}

$query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT AQuenteSan AS AQuenteSan1, AFriaSan AS AFriaSan1, AQuenteSann, AFriaSann, AQuenteSannn, AFriaSannn, Ferro, Realizacao AS Realizacao1

FROM raddb.Reg_legExt WHERE Realizacao BETWEEN ? AND ?");

$query1->execute([$inicio, $fim]);

$json1 = array();
while($row1=$query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row1);

    $json1[]= [(string)$AQuenteSan1, (string)$AFriaSan1, (string)$AQuenteSann, (string)$AFriaSann, (string)$AQuenteSannn, (string)$AFriaSannn, 
    (string)$Ferro, (string)$Realizacao1];
}

$merged = array_merge($json, $json1);

echo json_encode($merged);
```

The data returned is the following:

```
(2) [Array(10), Array(8)] 
0: (10) ['0.40', '0.20', '0.10', '61.00', '50.00', '19.00', '49.00', '20.00', '6.50', '2023-11-20'] 
1: (8) ['0.60', '0.45', '0.10', '61.00', '50.00', '19.00', '49.00', '2023-11-20']
```

But what I intended was for the data to return like this:

```
(1) [Array(18)] 
        0: (18) ['0.40', '0.20', '0.10', '61.00', '50.00', '19.00', '49.00', '20.00', '6.50', '2023-11-20', '0.60', '0.45', '0.10', '61.00', '50.00', '19.00', '49.00', '2023-11-20']
```

This way, all data sent by json_encode would be within the same element.

Can you help me get this result?

Comment: This does not appear to be your real code, because if I run https://onlinephp.io/c/a29ef I get exactly what you'd expect: an array with 18 elements. Also note that you're not dealing with JSON in your code anywhere, so don't name your variables `$json` and `$json1` unless you want to confuse future readers (including yourself). Name them after what they are, such as `$leg_int_matches` and `$leg_ext_matches` or something.